# How do you find multiple recursive formulas for the same explicit formula?

Tags: sequences-and-series

*Sorry in advance for weird formatting, I'm not too familiar with this website*

Recently I've stumbled upon the problem of how the sequence of squares seems to have multiple recursive formula for the same explicit formula $a_n=n^2.$

There are two recursive formulas for this equation being

$$a_1=1$$

$$a_{n+1}=a_n+2n+1$$

and

$$a_1=1$$

$$a_n=a_{n-1}+2n-1$$

I found the top equation rather easily, changing n in the explicit equation to $(n+1)$, then simplifying and subtracting out the original $n^2$, but I couldn't find out how to find the bottom equation, I prefer the format of the bottom equation personally, so if anyone could explain to me how to get that second equation that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In the first recurrence equation, take $n:=n-1$.

Comment: The two equations are equivalent

Comment: 2(n+1) - 1 = 2n + 1

Comment: @Arnaldo so would that mean that the second equation can only be found after the first recursive equation is found? Or is there any other way to get the second recurrence equation initially?

Comment: @Hunter: If you find the first equation intuitive, you should feel the same regarding to the second equation. First equation thinks of $a_{n+1}$ as a function of $a_n$. The second starts to think of $a_n$